# downgrade android support library , Building mozilla fennec

Tags: android, firefox, mozilla, fennec

I am trying to Build Firefox for Android. 
I followed all the instructions here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Android#Android_NDK_and_SDK_version_notes

I ran `./mach Build`, the terminal shows the following error:

```
193:09.18 Found 1 drawables in '/home/himani/mozilla-central/mobile/android/base/resources' for 'webmaker': ['drawable-xhdpi/suggestedsites_webmaker.png']
193:09.18 Found 1 drawables in '/home/himani/mozilla-central/mobile/android/base/resources' for 'restricted_mozilla': ['drawable-xhdpi/suggestedsites_restricted_mozilla.png']
193:09.19 /home/himani/mozilla-central/obj-arm-linux-androideabi/mobile/android/base/res/raw/suggestedsites.json updated
193:09.45 Read 3 engines: [u'Google', u'Yahoo', u'Bing']
193:09.45 Default engine is 'Google'.
193:09.45 Region 'US': Read 3 engines: [u'Yahoo', u'Google', u'Bing']
193:09.45 Region 'US': Default engine is 'Yahoo'.
193:09.46 /home/himani/mozilla-central/obj-arm-linux-androideabi/mobile/android/base/res/raw/browsersearch.json updated
193:10.08 gecko-thirdparty.jar
193:10.49 sync-thirdparty.jar
193:13.66 Note: /home/himani/mozilla-central/mobile/android/base/SysInfo.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
193:13.66 Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
193:27.64 Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
193:27.64 Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
193:27.65 Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
193:27.65 Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
193:30.13 geckoview_resources.zip
193:31.97 gecko-mozglue.jar
193:33.38     (skipping file '.mkdir.done' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
193:33.38     (skipping file '.mkdir.done' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
193:44.11 /home/himani/.mozbuild/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/styles_base.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
193:44.11 
193:44.11 /home/himani/.mozbuild/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/styles_base_text.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
193:44.11 
193:44.20 make[5]: *** [.aapt.deps] Error 1
193:44.20 make[5]: *** Deleting file `.aapt.deps'
193:44.20 make[5]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
193:47.91 Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
193:47.92 Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
193:47.92 Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
193:47.92 Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
193:48.83 make[4]: *** [mobile/android/base/libs] Error 2
193:48.83 make[3]: *** [libs] Error 2
193:48.83 make[2]: *** [default] Error 2
193:48.84 make[1]: *** [realbuild] Error 2
193:48.84 make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Now, I think the problem arises because the Android build SDK and Support library versions are different. But I am not being able to downgrade my support library to an earlier version. 
Can anyone suggest me a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reported in the [MDN page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Android#Android_NDK_and_SDK_version_notes) (see the "2015/08/26 "Support library 23 and SDK 22/23" note), [here's](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/mobile-firefox-dev/2015-August/001401.html) a mailing list exchange on how to downgrade the library.

In short, download and extract [this zip](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/support_r22.2.1.zip) into $ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/ . I'd suggest to perform a backup first.